# UploadFile Interface can't be found

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I need to use the interface of @UploadedFile decorator, but I don't find if it's already defined or I have to.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator `@UploadedFile()` can be found in the `@nestjs/common` package. You can just add it into your import statement

```js
import { /* rest of your imports */, UploadedFile } from '@nestjs/common';
```

[Here is the link to the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#basic-example)

Comment: I know where the decorator is. You have something like @UploadedFile file. I want to know that file what class/interface implements

Comment: [Here it is in the source code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/decorators/http/route-params.decorator.ts#L73) the closest thing to a class or interface that it implements is that it is a `ParameterDecorator`. Other than that, not much else to it.

Comment: I think that if you are using Typescript at least define something like: `{ name: string, mimeType: string, buffer: Buffer} ` , don't you?

Comment: You may be looking more for the `FileInterceptor` pipe which takes a fileName and an optional object of `Multer` options. All the `@UploadedFile()` decorator does for you is allows you access to the file after `multer` has parsed it, similar to how `@Request()` allows you to use the `req` object or `@Body()` gets you `req.body` after parsing. I haven't worked much with the decorator, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do at the moment.